# Find the Expected value and variance of X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2bVl.png]

I need to find the find expected value of $x$ using iterated expectation and then find the variance of $x$.

So far, I have found the mean and variance of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ as: mean$=y/2$ and Variance$=y^2/12$

Comment: Find $E[X] = \int E[X \mid Y=y] f_Y(y) \, dy$ or as $\int\int x f_{X,Y} \, dx \, dy$ and similarly $E[X^2]$

Comment: @Henry would the limits be x and 1?

Comment: The first integral is over the support of $Y$ i.e. $0 \lt y \lt 1$.  Finding  $f_Y(y)$ may require a little more thought, though the answer is simple

Comment: @Henry I have fY(y)=1/y=1. Where do i go from here?

Comment: @ceph would i need to use differentiation?

Answer (score 1):

You have here all the pieces you need. You have found $E(X|Y)$, $V(X|Y)$, and $f_Y$.

"Iterated expectation", which you say you are to use, tells us that $E(X)=E(E(X|Y))$.

By what you have told us, this in turn equals $E(y/2)$. Since you have $f_Y$, you can use it to calculate the expectation of $y/2$.

Another useful fact here is that $V(X)=E(V(X|Y)) + V(E(X|Y))$. This is especially useful since, again, you have already found all the pieces needed to fill in this formula. By what you have given us, this quantity equals $E(y^2/12) + V(y/2)$. And once again, since you have already found $f_Y$, you can use it to calculate both $E(y^2/12)$ and $V(y/2)$.

Comment: would i need to differentiate?

Comment: None of what I described requires differentiation.