# Finding the variance of x

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the joint probability density function
>   $$
> f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> \frac{1}{y}, & 0 < x < y, & 0< y< 1 \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise} &
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>   Find the variance of $X$.

I need to find the variance of $x$. So far, I have found the mean and variance of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$ as:

$$ mean=\frac{y}{2}$$ and $$Variance=\frac{y^2}{12}$$

I know i must use $$V(X)=E(V(X|Y))+V(E(X|Y))$$, but i am getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Please write your function in your question rather than on an attached image. It's quite annoying to keep switching back and forth

Comment: Sorry, i am unsure how to write the question correctly in the post

Comment: What answer are you getting?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am getting E(x)=1/4 and var(x)=7/144

Comment: X conditioned on $Y=y$ is uniform on $(0,y)$ where $Y$ itself is distributed as $U(0,1)$. Hence from the conditional mean and variance that you have, I get $V(X)=\frac3{16}$.

Comment: Seems like the same set of homework: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3432998/find-the-expected-value-and-variance-of-x.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing down the marginal $f_X$ instead of conditional distributions. $f_X(x)=\int_x^{1} \frac  1 y dy=-\log x$ for  $0<x<1$. The first and the second moments can be computed by making the substitution $u=\log x$. You can try this and see if you get the right answer.